# How to work with sqlite DataBase in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin.android

I searched for along time for how can I use a pre made Excel table, as a reading database in Xamarin.Android.
Of course I can't use it directly, so I tried many different ways. For example, convert to Json, upload to Firebase, and later download it, while the program runs, and fill the sqlite. This way is not effective aadn most of the time doesn't work.
Is there any chance, that someone could please explain or even give a tutorial on how to create sqlite database and work with it directly? If there any other worse or better ways to do it, please tell me.

Thank You!

Comment: Why did https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite not help you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use sqlite DataBase for Xamarin.Android, you could use `sqlite-net-pcl`.

Install from NuGet: `sqlite-net-pcl`

You could cgeck the MS docs from the link below for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm